# kafka-go library - fetch all records from latest poll as a slice of messages

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I am using the [segmentio/kafka-go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) library, specifically the kafka.Reader but it only reads 1 record at a time via the FetchMessage function. My setup looks like this currently:

```
dialer := &kafka.Dialer{
    Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
    DualStack: true,
    TLS:       buildTlsConfig(certPath, tlsEnabled),
}

// make a new kafka reader that is part of the given consumer group
r := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
    Brokers: []string{bootstrapBrokerAddress},
    GroupID: group,
    Topic:   topic,
    Dialer:  dialer,
})

// in a loop in a diff part of the code
m, err := kr.reader.FetchMessage(ctx)
```

For efficiency in my business logic, I want to read all messages from each poll iteration as a batch.  I was hoping for a simple function like this:

```
func (r *Reader) FetchMessages(ctx context.Context) ([]Message, error)
```

Or at least a method to check if there are more records fetched from the last poll so I can collect them myself, but I don't see anything like this in the api.  I know there are lower level functions on the Conn object, but I want to take advantage of the reader's consumer group handling.

Is there a simple way to fetch all the Messages from each poll as a slice?

Comment: On the same link you provided there is Read Batch function example

Comment: I saw this, but as mentioned in the question: I know there are lower level functions on the Conn object, but I want to take advantage of the reader's consumer group handling.

Answer (score -1):

On the same link you provided  there is example calling ReadBatch

```
// to consume messages
topic := "my-topic"
partition := 0

conn, err := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "localhost:9092", topic, partition)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to dial leader:", err)
}

conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(10*time.Second))
batch := conn.ReadBatch(10e3, 1e6) // fetch 10KB min, 1MB max

b := make([]byte, 10e3) // 10KB max per message
for {
    _, err := batch.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

if err := batch.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to close batch:", err)
}

if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to close connection:", err)
}
```

Comment: I saw this, but I want the consumer group handling provided by the reader, and would like to return a []Message slice.  I wonder if there is a slick way to still lean on all the stuff the reader does, but gather all Message objects from a poll iteration.

Comment: What about RecordReader and NewRecordReader? Didn't find an example though

Comment: How do you commit the messages after processing them when reading in batch?